# Is there a way to exclude the 'Create New Account' button from FB log in dialog?

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm updating an iOS app for kids that uses the FB connect API to post creations to their walls. Recently a 'create new account' button has appeared on the login dialog displayed in web view. Is there a simple way to exclude this without creating a custom UI and rewriting the whole FB functionality?

Thanks